# Integer parseInt method not found

Tags: java

I am trying to this code in which test out a simple method. In which you use a method which receives argument. The problem that is happening is with `Integer` parse int method.

The command prompt gives an error which is.

```
java:24:error:cannot find symbol

cholo=Integer.parseInt("123");

             ^
symbol: method parseInt(String)

location: class Integer

1 error
```

I am not sure what is causing this.

```
//Passing arguments in java

//this program demonstrates a method with a paramter

public class PassArg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        int k;
        int cholo;
        System.out.println(" I am passing values to displayValue ");


        displayValue(5);
        displayValue(x);
        displayValue(x * 4);
        k = 14;
        displayValue(14);
        cholo = Integer.parseInt("123");
        displayValue(cholo);
        System.out.println("now I am back in the main");
    }

    public static void displayValue(int num) {
        System.out.println("the value is " + num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you importing the Integer class correctly ?

Comment: @OneMoreError You shouldn' have to import `Integer` since it is in `java.lang` which is implicitly imported. Maybe he has his own `Integer` class?

Comment: No I do not know about that class. I did not import any other classes for this program.

Comment: Your code seems to work in my IDE. Can you please paste the imports in your code ?

Comment: @jamesFog: Yes, you're right. My bad!

Comment: The only possible explanation is that you have a different `Integer` class available at your class path... please confirm, that there is nothing else next to your `PassArg.java` file (namely no `Integer.java` mess).

Comment: Your code is working fine... there might be issue in your classpath

Comment: Yes you are right I noticed I do have another class called Integer in (the same folder as PassArg) where I did another program a couple of months ago. Do I have to delete this Integer.java class? for the program to work

Comment: @jamesFog Just rename it

Comment: Ok now the program works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only explanation I can think of is you have your own `Integer` class which you are getting (and not `java.lang.Integer`). Rename your other `Integer` class, or use the full qualified class name like

```
int cholo = java.lang.Integer.parseInt("123");
System.out.println(cholo);
```

Output is

```
123
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a class "Integer" in your src folder that is overiding the default Integer Java Class.  Look at your import statements.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be something with your JDK build path, try to verify the path to your JDK by right clicking your project->properties->build path and make sure it's pointing to your JDK path. Also, try cleaning your project.